# An Issue Running Adobe Air App on iPhone Simulator

Tags: actionscript-3, air, ios-simulator

I'm trying to deploy an Adobe AIR application to an iPhone, and while building it as an ipa and deploying using itunes works, the app is not running correctly so I need to debug using the simulator, when trying to launch the simulator with `adt` I'm getting this error:

`Failed to find class DTiPhoneSimulatorSystemRoot at runtime.`

I'm calling `adt` with the following parameters:

`adt -installApp 
     -platform ios 
     -platformsdk /Applications/Xcode.app/.../SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.2.sdk
     -device ios-simulator
     -package package.ipa`

I'm using ADT version 23 and iPhoneSimulator 10.2 on macOS El Capitan

Comment: Try again with the latest AIR 24 SDK. Similar errors were reported on the AIR forums and it happened because AIR 23 wasn't compatible with the latest version of XCode.

Comment: @Mr.Phantom same result on AIR 24b

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in Air SDK 25 which is now available for download.